# Package structure convention of Android app and libraries

Tags: java, android, package

I've a question to the package structure of an Android app. I know that the convention is the same like in standard Java - using a domain in reverse order so I selected "com.myappname". And then I've some subpackages, for example "com.myappname.ui" for all my activities.
Now I also want to include some libraries or frameworks f.e. the aFileDialog. This library is packaged to "ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog".
But should I maintain this package name and use it parallel to my own app package or is it better or even necessary to rename it and make it to a subpackage of my own f.e. "com.myappname.daidalos.afiledialog"?

Comment: You should try it and see what happens. There is no problem using two different package namespaces for two different packages. The only reason I can think of to rename the package is if your package will be a library and you want library users to be able to use their own copy of "ar.com.daidolos.afiledialog".

Comment: Yes I can compile and build without any problems. Ok and there will also be no problem of different packages when publishing in Play Store?

Comment: no, no problem at all.